# Does it make sense to use ELK to collect page metrics?

Tags: postgresql, logging, analytics, rdbms, elastic-stack

We would like to collect some interesting user-related metrics on our website (e.g. "user edited profile", or "user clicked on downloaded file", etc.) and are thinking about using the ELK stack for this.

Is it a good idea to use Elasticsearch to store such events? Or would it make more sense to log them in our RDBMS?

What would be the advantages of using either of those?

(Side note: We already use Elasticsearch and PostgreSQL in our our stack.

Answer (score 1):

You could save your logs in any persistent solution out there and later decide what tool to use for analyzing them.

If you want to do some queries (manage your data on the fly/real-time) you could just directly parse/pipe the logs generated by your applications and send them to elastic search, the flow would be something like:

```
(your app) --> filebeat --> elasticsearch <-- Kibana
```

Just keep in mind that the [elk stack is not "cheap"](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/hardware.html) and based on your setup could become more expensive to maintain in long term.

At the end depends on your use case, both solutions you mention can be used to store data, but the way you extract/query data is the one that makes the difference.